# Почему не получается скачать файл по этой ссылке средствами PHP (403 ошибка)? Как исправить код, чтобы он работал?

Tags: php

Вот мой код:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru/instruction/1486389_manual.docx';

ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
$contextOptions = [
    "ssl" => [
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ],
];
$downloadedFile = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($contextOptions));

if ($downloadedFile === false) {
    $text = 'Ошибка при скачивании файла по ссылке: ' . $url;
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
    if (!empty($headers[0])) {
        $code = str_replace('HTTP / 1.1 ', '', $headers[0]);
        $text .= ', вот код ответа: ' . $code;
    }
    echo $text;
} else {
    echo 'Все отлично';
}
```

Мне выводится сообщение:

> Ошибка при скачивании файла по ссылке:
> https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru/instruction/1486389_manual.docx, вот код
> ответа: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Если я захожу на страницу через браузер, то никаких ошибок нет, документ docx отдается. То есть это не блокировка по IP.
Я пробовал менять useragent в коде - не помогло. То есть это не блокировка по Useragent.

Как мне исправить мой код, чтобы он работал?

Comment: Там стоит CloudFlare защита от ботов. То есть, это не прямая ссылка, а ссылка на веб страницу, на которой есть JS, скрытая форма, и так далее, которые решают некую задачу, генерируют токен, выводят капчу (если надо), и уже потом, выдают вам оригинал страницы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и как это обойти? Возможно ли это обойти?

Comment: Ну, берите скрипт и расшифровывайте, авось получится. Капчи и другие защиты от автоматизации ведь не просто так придуманы, верно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я запускаю сайт https://www.vseinstrumenti.ru/ и не вижу CloudFlare. На этом сайте нет CloudFlare.

Comment: Наверно поэтому вы можете главную страницу без 403 ошибки получить, попробуйте. Ну а потом попробуйте получить HTML страницы загружаемого файла, вы получите там [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfSTQ.png) по виду, а в HTML будет [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ0eg.png), внимание на значения по типу `__cf_chl_tk`, что переводится как "**C**loud**F**lare **Ch**a**l**lenge **T**o**k**en". Вам еще сайт повесит Cookie `__cf_bm`, которая также является частью защиты. Так что, давайте не будет спорить есть там или нет, я всю информацию почти всегда проверяю перед написанием.